# "invert" color ramp in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

How do I invert the color ramp for an raster data in QGIS 3.0?

I tried to find the invert menu in single pseudocolor render type in QGIS 3.0 but I don't see it there.

I was using QGIS 3.0.3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It moved into the `Color ramp` drop-down menu.

[image]

Enjoy! :)

Comment: That's a very subtle design of UI.